# html table td with 1 column and 2 rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table with 4x4 dimension, but with one TD to occupy the space of one column and 2 lines ...

Like the example below ...

http://s2.postimg.org/c5s7am6tl/table.png

Comment: It's recommended to try to do some research or at least write some code before posting questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
<td rowspan="2" colspan="2"> </td>
```

The rest is just standard table structure.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't make sense anymore; you want the first row to have 2 cells, and the second row to have 1 cell (because the cell above with rowspan will fill the extra space).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation here:
http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Comment: I would not advocate w3schools as a good source of documentation. Here's why: http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: I wouldn't advocate this kind of question (without any research effort), I just googled "rowspan html table" and that was the first result. Cool link though, thanks dude!

Comment: It's true, it's not a good question either. I didn't really know this before just now, but answers should not be link-only; see this post about it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: I just didn't want to provide a snippet of code so the OP could blindly copy and paste  without, at least, reading something about the concept. But you are correct, answers should be properly elaborated.